# angularjs: passing data to the ui-dialog directive

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I'm using the $dialog directive to show a dialog in my application. The dialog is opened from another directive :

```
angular.module('axa.directDebit.directives').directive("mandateHistoryDetail", ['$dialog', function($dialog) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<a class="btn btn-small" ng-click="openDialog()">Détail</a>',
    scope: {
        model: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.openDialog = function(){
            var d = $dialog.dialog({
                backdrop: true,
                keyboard: true,
                backdropClick: true,
                dialogFade: true,
                templateUrl: 'app/directDebit/views/mandates.detail.history.detail.html',
                controller: 'mandates.detail.history.detail.ctrl',
                resolve: {
                    data: function () {
                        return scope.model;
                    }
            }
            });
            d.open();
        }
    },
    controller: 'mandates.detail.history.detail.ctrl'
}
}]);
```

The problem I'm having, is that from the dialog's controller, I would like to access the calling directive's scope. In particular the 'model' property in the above code.

I've tried using resolve, but the from the dialog controller I don't know how to get hold of data.

Any idea what I should change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dialog controller, you should just add it as a dependency.

You called it `data` so it should be -

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('mandates.detail.history.detail.ctrl', 
                                        function($scope, data){ 
 ...
});
```

Just as a side note - I would extract the behavior of opening the $dialog to an outside view controller and not inside a directive, 'cause it looks like application logic to me and directives should aspire to be reusable.